# Есть огромные SQL дампи, нужно создать локальный проект как уменьшить объем базы, для локального проекта?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть ли ресурсы которые могут уменьшить объем дамп файла  учитывая foreign key -и ?
Как уменьшить размер дамп файла и собрать  локал  проект с минимальным объемом базы данных ?

Пытался вручную удалить строки из дамп файла но он огромный  много времени займет и ошибок не избежать.

Comment: Речь идет о выборочной выгрузке данных? По каким критериям нужно пропускать данные? Вы хотите их задавать как параметр процедуры дампа?

Comment: Критерий такой,  если имеется миллион строк лога, пусть остаётся  100, для теста, остальные не  нужны, для локальных работ .

Comment: Сложность ещчо в том что я не знаю структуру таблиц.

Comment: Импортируйте весь дамп и затем сделайте новую, частичную, выгрузку. Парсинг и корректировка дампа, да ещё с сохранением ссылочной целостности - дело совершенно безнадёжное.

Comment: А как сделать дамп с частичной вигрузкой и с сохранением ссылочной целостности, например задать макс лимит  100 строк ?

Comment: Не все таблицы имеют foreign key-и,  те которые не имеют можно свободно урезать